# Passing a function pointer as non-type template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

I have this template function, which is working well:

```
    template<typename RES, typename... PARMS> SQInteger GlobalBind(RES(*fn)(PARMS... parms), const char *sqName, HSQUIRRELVM v)
```

Which is called like this :

```
GlobalBind(aFunction, "aName", vm);
```

Its scope is binding function `fn` to a scripting engine.

Using it in this way, I must keep the `fn` pointer AND a proxy template pointer inside of the scripting engine; the proxy template (not shown here) is called with `fn` as parameter, does some stuff, and then calls `fn`.

What I'd like to achieve is to remove the `fn` pointer from the function call, and put it into the template as a parameter, something like this:

```
template<typename RES, typename... PARMS, RES(*fn)(PARMS...)> SQInteger GlobalBind(const char *sqName, HSQUIRRELVM v)
```

So, a specific template is instantiated for each different `fn`, which means that I could avoid the `fn` pointer in the scripting language; the call should be:

```
GlobalBind<aFunction>("aName", vm);
```

The template declaration is accepted by the compiler, but the call brings errors, even adding the parameter types before `aFunction`, like this (assuming `aFunction` returns and `int` and has `const char *` as a parameter):

```
GlobalBind<int, const char *, aFunction>("aName", vm);
```

Is there a way to achieve this result (the former, without a parameters list)?

EDIT:
to simplify the question, is the template

```
template<typename RES, typename... PARMS, RES(*fn)(PARMS...)> RES TEST(PARMS... parms) {
    return fn(parms...);
}
```

a valid one ? And if yes... how should it be called ?
I tried this :

```
int testfn(const char *s) { return strlen(s); }
TEST<testfn>("aString");   << ERROR
TEST<int, const char *, testfn>("aString");  << ERROR
```

EDIT2:
This one :

```
template<int (*fn)(const char *)> int TEST2(const char *s) {
    return fn(s);
}
TEST2<testfn>("aString");
```

works, but it's not useful for my purpose

Comment: Why not simply use `std::function`?

Comment: Are you by chance using C++17 features?

Comment: Because the engine requires just ONE function pointer (standard C pointer) to do the call. I already modified it to bring 2 of them by now, but I'd like to keep it as unmodified as possible. And I shouldn't use stl.

Comment: No, C++11 with (maybe) some GCC extensions at most

Comment: (I could try to rebuild the toolchain with a more recent GCC, but it's quite time expensive and it should be for a really good reason... the toolchain must run on windows, linux and osx)

Comment: I would say that if you do heavy template code like this, you want to use recent compiler as much as possible at many improvements made to C++ 14 and 17 are intended to simplify that kind of code. So maybe, it might be preferable to invest time in upgrading rather that writing more complicated code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template<class T, T t>
struct constant_t:std::integral_constant<T,t>{
  constexpr operator T()const { return t; }
  constexpr constant_t(){}
};

#define TYPEDARG(...) \
  typename std::decay<decltype(__VA_ARGS__)>::type, \
  __VA_ARGS__
```

Now `constant_t<TYPEDARG(foo)>` is a type whose instances can be invoked if `foo` is a non-overloaded function and they call `foo`.

In [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) this becomes:

```
template<auto x>
using constant_t=std::integral_constant<std::decay_t<decltype(x)>,x>;
```

and use is simply `constant_t<foo>`, without all that extra noise.

```
template<class Fn, class R, class... Args>
R test(Args&&... args) {
  return Fn{}(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int foo( int a, int b ) { return a+b; }

int r = test< constant_t<TYPEDARG(foo)>, int, int, int >( 3, 4 );
```

Comment: I'm totally lost here :-)
Could you please add an example ?

Comment: You don't need the `typename` here, do you?

Comment: @Quentin Actually, `decay_t` isn't C++11, so I do need it and a `::type`.  Fixed.

Comment: @max example added

Comment: Now I see, thank you!
The big problem is that it doesn't work for overloaded functions.

Comment: @max The name of an overloaded function does not name any object, but rather a way to determine which object to interact with in certain contexts.  But yes.  Now, you could pass in the signature to `integral_constant` and thus force an overload to be selected.  And maybe through some trickery reuse that signature elsewhere.  But it woudl heavily depend on use.

Comment: @yakk Yes, the purpose is a proxy template that calls my function after doing some things, get its result, do some other things and return a value.
Something like int DISPATCH<RES, FN, ARGS...>(). I then need the callable address of this template. I can do it passing the fn as argument **to the function**, but then I have to take BOTH fn AND the template function address with me, which I want to avoid if possible. Your solution would be perfect (maybe with some helping macro), but I need it also for overloaded functions and (later) for member functions...

Comment: @Max Why not just carry a `std::function<R(Args...)>` around?

Comment: @Yakk, because I should modify the scripting engine code, which expects (and stores) a C function pointer... and I'd rather avoid stl usage, if possible (not a strong requisite, indeed. I'm working on a microcontroller, and I've a limited port of stl on it).
By now I've already made a small mod to it, to make it store both the dispatcher AND the fn, so I can use the non-arg-template version, but I'm looking for a smarter alternative

Answer (score 0):

Found an (ugly) solution, but it works also for overloaded functions :

```
int myFunc(const char *s) {
    return strlen(s);
}

const char *myFunc(int i) {
    return "it's me";
}

template<typename FN, FN fn, typename RES, typename... PARMS> RES _DISPATCH(PARMS... parms) {
    return fn(parms...);
}

#define DISPATCH(RES, FN, ...) _DISPATCH<RES(*)(__VA_ARGS__), FN, RES, __VA_ARGS__>

Cout() << (void *)DISPATCH(int, myFunc, const char *) << "\n";
Cout() << (void *)DISPATCH(const char *, myFunc, int) << "\n";
```

The DISPATCH() macro builds a dispatcher of which I can get the C address and pass to my scripting engine.
I'd rather to have a solution without macros, indeed. Still open to better solutions!